# Is it possible to code something for automatically run multiple python files consecutively in cmd

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have some codes that will take time to run for a while. Is it possible that I create a new file that has a code like

```
import run001
import run002
import run003
```

and run this in `cmd` to make it automatically run other three `.py` files (`run001.py`, `run002.py`, `run003.py`) from the same folder? This `import` way works only the first file but not automatically continue the second one.

Comment: just type exactly that into a text file and name it `runner.bat` or something like that (assuming you're on windows)

Comment: If you have access to the three original files (`run001`, `run002` and `run003`), just factor the relevant code into a function and call the function from the outer script.

Comment: Thanks @bendl. Just to clarify someone. Make new file named runner.bat. In that file, type `python run001.py` (and other files line by line). In `cmd`, type `runner.bat`

Comment: Should work, yep

Answer (score 0):

Yes we can call a command in a python script directly with the use of either
`subprocess` module or `os.system`. Here is the link for official documentation.

1. [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html)
2. [os.system](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.system)

Though i would suggest you to stick to `subprocess` module as it is newer and provides more control to user on the other hand `os.system` just spawns a process and returns the return code

`subprocess` module allows us to spawn new process through our Python script, so let us assume you want to list all the files in your directory, this can be achieved by a simple call to `subprocess.call()`

```
import subprocess as sub

sub.call(yourCommand) #to pass a single command
sub.call(commandList) #to pass a multiple commands
```